# Straight segment tool not working when editing in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, polygon, editing, segment

[image]

The straight segment tool is not working. I kept pressing right click to make it work but nothing happens. I'm working on ArcMap 10.7 .

Answer (score 1):

You start the line by clicking on your left key on your mouse, then if you need to constrain the length for example you right click to get the context menu.